# PL/SQL XMLTYPE ORA-30625

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmltype

I'm working with a web service that returns the output below. I'm having a hard time building the XMLTYPE variable from the output. I get the following error when trying to output the `CreateUserSessionFromInstanceResult`

> ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed

```
procedure xmltest is

str_xml varchar2(32000);
v_xml XMLTYPE;

BEGIN
str_xml :='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <soap:Body>
                <CreateUserSessionFromInstanceResponse xmlns="http://archer-tech.com/webservices/">
                    <CreateUserSessionFromInstanceResult>4FFABEE05C4910A31FEC75D5FEDCDFB5</CreateUserSessionFromInstanceResult>
                </CreateUserSessionFromInstanceResponse>
            </soap:Body>
       </soap:Envelope>';
v_xml := XMLTYPE(str_xml);
HTP.P(v_xml.extract('//CreateUserSessionFromInstanceResult/text()').getstringval());

END;
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is on this line

```
HTP.P(v_xml.extract('//CreateUserSessionFromInstanceResult/text()').getstringval());
```

You're getting an error because your XPath expression

```
//CreateUserSessionFromInstanceResult/text()
```

matches nothing, and so `extract(...)` returns `NULL`.  Of course, you can't call `getstringval()` on `NULL`, hence the error you see.

The reason your XPath isn't matching is because of namespaces.  The `xmlns` attribute on the `<CreateUserSessionFromInstanceResponse>` element sets the namespace of this element and of the `<CreateUserSessionFromInstanceResult>` element it contains to be `"http://archer-tech.com/webservices/"`.  On the other hand, your XPath expression is searching for the element with the name `CreateUserSessionFromInstanceResult` in the default namespace, `""`.

The fix is to add a third parameter to `extract` that declares this namespace.  You do this in the same way as it appears in the XML:

```sql
HTP.P(v_xml.extract('//CreateUserSessionFromInstanceResult/text()',
                    'xmlns="http://archer-tech.com/webservices/"').getstringval());
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar case and adding the extra parameter didn't work for me.

For me, the solution was to check if node exists and do a null check before using getstringval, like this:

`if v_xml.existsnode('//CreateUserSessionFromInstanceResult', 'xmlns="http://archer-tech.com/webservices/"') > 0 and v_xml.extract('//CreateUserSessionFromInstanceResult/text()', 'xmlns="http://archer-tech.com/webservices/"') is not null then
HTP.P(v_xml.extract('//CreateUserSessionFromInstanceResult/text()', 'xmlns="http://archer-tech.com/webservices/"').getstringval());
end if;`

Doing only the null check is probably enough.